# Overlapping task duration aggregation in DAX Hierarchy

Tags: dax, hierarchy, timeline

**SCENARIO:**
Monitor “Task” duration. Purpose is to track trend in changing Durations.
There is a framework that stores information about tasks in place.
There is a hierarchy setup using parent/child ID.
Columns; Task_ID, Parent_Task_ID, Start_Time,  End_Time, Duration.
[image: Task Execution timeline]
[image: Task hierarchy]
[image: Task Table]
A hierarchy has been set up With Calculated Columns
Depth, Path, Level1-Level4. (according to DAX Patterns on Hierarchy)
Measures; Browsedepth and RowDepth has been set up to remove blanks in the report setup for empty levels.

DAX;
Sum Hierarchy = 
VAR Val = [Sum Duration]  
VAR ShowRow=[BrowseDepth] <= [RowDepth] 
RETURN IF(ShowRow,Val)

**CHALLENGE:**
In the Task table all durations are correct, so there are no need to aggregate the duration of the children up to parent.
In Daxpatterns connected to hierarchies in the examples I have found, there are always aggregation up from children to parent, as the black numbers in the matrix under are showing
[image]

The  goal is to find a way to create a measure that avoid aggregation from children to parent, and present the "Blue numbers in the picture above.

Do anyone have any pointers on the pattern or logic to use, it would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Atle Røen

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to use MAX( 'Task'[Duration] ) and filter on the last task execution. Simple when you finally find the answer :D

DAX;

Max Task duration - Last run:=
CALCULATE (
MAX( 'Task'[Duration] ),
LASTDATE ( (
FILTER (
VALUES ( 'Task'[Start_Time] ),
MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) >= 'Task'[Start_Time]
)
) )
)

Task duration - Last run - Hier:=
VAR Val = [Max Task duration - Last run]
VAR ShowRow = [BrowseDepth] <= [MaxNodeDepth]
RETURN IF(ShowRow,Val)